# Objective-cからC関数を呼びたい

Tags: objective-c

Objective-cからC関数を呼びたいのですが

```
struct TEST_STR {
    int a;
    int b;
}
void test(TEST_STR& teststr);
```

Objective-Cから呼ぶにはどのようにしたらよいのでしょうか。
下記のようにすると、
Bad receiver type 'void (*)(TEST_STR &)'と怒られてしまいます。
パラメータの指定のさせ方が悪いのでしょうか。

```
TEST_STR teststr;
[test:&teststr]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TEST_STR&`と言うのはC++の参照型ですので、Objective-Cではコンパイルできません。Xcodeをご使用でしたら、ソーフファイルの拡張子を`.m`から`.mm`に変更することで、Objective-C++としてコンパイルされますので、通常のC++関数のように呼び出せるようになります。

```
TEST_STR teststr;
test(teststr);
```

Comment: な、なるほど…。Objective-cとC++が入交りでなんだかよく分からなくなってきました。
C++の場合、アドレス渡しの場合&を付けると思うのですが、そのような使い方はしないのでしょうか。。。

Comment: 参照型はポインターを渡すのとは別物で、代入や実引数として渡す際に&は付けません。これはCにはないC++独自のものです。「アドレス渡し」という言葉は誰が使い始めたのか知りませんが、アドレス(ポインタ)を値渡ししているだけなので不要な言い回しのように思います。参照渡しというのは古いFORTRAN言語なんかにもあった機構で、C言語ではポインタを明示的に扱えるようにする代わりに参照渡しの機能を省いてしまったのですが、いろいろ使いにくい部分もあってC++でまた復活したわけです。「アドレス渡しの場合&を付ける」と覚えるより「引数の型がポインタなんだからアドレス(ポインタ)を取り出すために&を付けている」(前置の&は"address of"と読んだりします)と覚えた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 「引数の型がポインタなんだからアドレス(ポインタ)を取り出すために&を付けている」なんだかしっくりきました。Objective-cまだコードを読むのにぜんぜんなれず、お試しお試ししているものの頭が混乱してきそうです。"[]"ってなんぞー？ってところから始まり・・・勉強してせめてソースが読めるようにならねばです。。。